# How to model a binary vector by the Beta-Bernoulli distribution in R or Python？

Tags: prediction, binary-data, beta-distribution

I have a set of data $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$;e.g:$x=(0.1,0.003,0.78,...)$
which follows a beta distribution. Since $x_i$ in my data $x :x_i ~ Bernoulli(p)$, where $p$ is the prior of average $x$ and follows the Beta prior distribution, $p~Beta( α, β)$. So is there any R or python script to model a binary vector by the Beta-Bernoulli distribution from my data $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Is this really what your data looks like? If the xi I were to follow a Bernoulli distribution, should it not be x=(0,1,0,0,1,1,0...)? I.e. all 1 or 0?

If you have that kind of 0-1 data it's pretty easy to model. E.g. the `aod` R package can fit beta-binomial data (and e.g. in the `rstan` R package or the `pystan` python pacakge you could easily fit a hierachical model of this type either using maximum-likelihood or in a Bayesian way after specifying it in the Stan modeling language). Obviously, any package for beta-binomial data can deal with beta-Bernoulli/binary data, because that's just the special case with 1 binomial sample per unit.

If you only have the (binomial) proportions as you seem to show in your example data, then beta-regression may be what you could use. However, that has its problems, because for a small finite number of samples the observed proportions have a rather discrete distribution. On the other hand, if the observed proportions are based on huge numbers of samples that does not vary too much across units, that may be a non-problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. My data xi  is  the methylated ratio between the number of  aligned methylated and total reads  of the CpG site i in a region. Now I want to convert the ratio xi to a binary value 1 or 0 represents methylated or unmeylated status of CpG site i. Since I can get the average methylated ration for this region.  So Is there any function can convert my methylated ratio to methylated status?